# Get data from multiple web pages in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am new to PowerBI. I am trying to build my data model using the following data. I am using the getdata feature of PowerBI and web as a source.

https://www.fifa.com/worldcup/statistics/players/goal-scored

As you will see, this web page has three data pages with max length of 50.

How do I get data for three pages into PowerBI? As when pages are changed, the URL does not change.

Thank you in advance.